# Use panda3D in 2.7.3 OSX Lion

Tags: python, bash, panda3d

I have currently Panda3D working in the ppython version that is shipped with Panda3D. But how do I link Panda3D to the python version shipped with OSX Lion 2.7.1?

I read things about ~/.bash_profile and I tried the following including the rest of the bash profile:

```
# Setting PATH for EPD-7.2-2
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/EPD64.framework/Versions/Current/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH

export PYTHONPATH="/Developer/Panda3D/lib/direct":$PYTHONPATH

export PYTHONPATH

MKL_NUM_THREADS=1
export MKL_NUM_THREADS
```

But I still get an

```
ImportError: No module named direct.showbase.ShowBase
```

Comment: Solution!!:
Do a find search for the Panda3D.pth as this solved my problem.

sudo cp /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/Panda3D.pth /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/

Comment: Can someone set this question to solved? As I am not allowed to do it myself.... :-\

Answer (score 3):

The following two lines worked for me on Lion (I also had to set python to prefer 32 bit)

```
sudo cp /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/Panda3D.pth /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/
export VERSIONER_PYTHON_PREFER_32_BIT=yes
```

The export command should be put into .bashrc or equivalent.